# HASKELL -- function to loop over a do block?

Tags: string, list, haskell, filter, text-files

I have a do block and want to loop over it few times.

Comment: sorry, your question isn't clear, at all, and I voted to close. if you edit it into clarity, please @ ping me here in the comments (i.e. write a comment starting with @w and then choose my name) and I'll vote to reopen. cheers. :)

Comment: @WillNess Hi, I modified my question, I hope it's more clear now. thank you

Comment: no, it's not. you really have to add some actual code. :) also, don't say what you want your code to "do", say what results you want it to achieve. :)

Comment: If you have a function `f :: a -> IO b`, you can use `mapM f someList` to apply `f` for each element of the list.

Comment: @WillNess it's done sorry, thank you. it's not the real code but just to put it more clear

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't want to apply anything on the list but just use its length as number to execute the second block

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways you can go about doing this.

```
import Control.Monad

foo :: IO ()
foo = putStrLn "Hello there!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
   let someList = [1,4,9]


   forM_ someList $ \_ -> foo  -- Iterate over all values in the list
                               -- (ignoring the actual value)

   
   mapM_ (const foo) someList  -- Another way to write the same thing

   
   replicateM_ (length someList) foo  -- Repeat a constant number of times


   let go 0 = return ()   -- Small helper function
       go n = do          -- defining the loop
         foo
         go $ n-1
   go $ length someList
```

Comment: @letftaroundabout thank you, I tried this examples but when I try to apply them to another do block instead of foo, it doesn't work.

Comment: It does work even with an inline `do` block with `forM_`. If not, there's something wrong with your `do` block. Just define `foo` with the `IO ()` type (always use explicit type signatures) as the `do` block in question, then the compiler will guide you to what's wrong where.

Comment: ok, I will try that thank you

Comment: It works but basically my do block has a parameter, do you know how I can add it because I got this error = Invalid type signature: missedQuotes relevantQuotes :: ...
            Should be of form <variable> :: <type>

Comment: How about you read a basic Haskell tutorial before asking lots of questions? — The type signature of a (single-argument) function should be `functionName :: ArgumentType -> ResultType`. In your example presumably `foo :: [String] -> IO ()`.

Comment: Trust me, I read a lot and spend hours before asking. thank you for help